# Send mail works with command linux but not with PHP

Tags: php, linux, email

I have many emails, gmail and other and I try to send an email to each. Actually, only 1 email receive the message, the other, gmail for example, doesn't.

With linux : The command `echo "Hi" | mail -s "test" xxxxxxxx@gmail.com` works fine.

But with PHP, the mail do not go....

I have no error in my mail.log. Have you any ideas ?

Thanks !

Edit : I'am on a linux server.

Comment: php's `mail()` is useless garbage. try using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer instead, both of which offer far better diagnostics for mail problems.

Comment: Show us http://whathaveyoutried.com - maybe by using a http://sscce.org

Comment: Is your SMTP configured and is the PHP set to use it? Show us your PHP code and the error you get, please.

Comment: I have many servers and i never have problems, in my php.ini i have SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$body = $mailBody;
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxxxx@example.com'); 
$mail->AddAddress('yyyyy@example.com', 'Your Name');

$mail->Subject = 'The subject';
$mail->MsgHTML('The body');
$mail->Send();
```